# Ignore sudo in bash script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, sudo

I have a small bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch dummy.txt
```

If I execute this script with `sudo` then it will create `dummy.txt` which will be **root protected**.

What I want to do is:

Regardless of whether this script is executed using `sudo` or a normal user, the file `dummy.txt` should **not** be root protected.

Comment: Whatever you mean by "root protected", you can use `chown` and `chmod` in your script to set ownership and permissions as desired.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "root protected". Do you mean that only the root user can read/write (eg file permissions are set to something like 700), or that the root user is the file owner?

Comment: @DoritoStyle sorry for the confusion. By **root protected**, I meant **root user** is the file owner.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could test if the script is being run via `sudo` using the `EUID` and `SUDO_USER` variables, and then execute `touch` as `SUDO_USER` if true - something like

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]] && [[ -n $SUDO_USER ]]; then
  sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" touch dummy.txt
else
  touch dummy.txt
fi
```

Comment: Note that `==` used for string comparison. Since `$EUID` is supposed to return integer value, I'd recommend you use `-ed` comparison.   [Spaces are allowed in usernames](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148044/85039) , so probably quote the `$SUDO_USER` variable. Otherwise, good answer - this is something I personally would use.

Comment: @steeldriver this is what I was looking for. thanks!!

Comment: You could have the script re-run itself with `sudo -u` if it detects that it's running as root.  The OP talked about having multiple commands in one script.  But be careful to avoid an infinite loop on errors.

Comment: There's no word splitting  within `[[...]]` so not strictly necessary to quote the variable within the if statement @Serg and I gues `-ed` was a typo for `-eq`

Comment: @Arronical yes, that was typo for `-eq`. Didn't know `[[` doesn't have word splitting. Thanks. Personally, I'd still quote for the sake of good scripting habits

Comment: @Serg I think the same, I always err on the side of more quotes rather than less, I don't actually know what those edge cases where you shouldn't quote are. I just asked a question on U&L to find out.

Comment: @Arronical that question has been asked before, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/85039  Basically, if you want variable to be treated as single entity, use quotes. If you want contents to to be treated as several different words, don't use quotes.

Comment: @Serg thanks for the `==` catch, don't know why I didn't spot that (it was late here...)

Comment: You can do integer comparisons like this: `(( EUID == 0 )) && [[ -n $SUDO_USER ]]`. Note the optional omitting of the dollar sign and the use of `==` instead of the, IMO ugly, `-eq`.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `sudo su -` doesn't leave `SUDO_USER` in the environment, so this would leave a root-protected file in that case.

Answer (score 9):

If your script is not meant to be run as `root`, the safest way to solve the problem is to abort the execution of the script at the very beginning:

```
if [ "$EUID" = 0 ]; then
   echo "This script must NOT be run as root" 
   exit 1
fi
```

Optionally, you can re-execute your script as a fallback user (e.g. `sudo -u FALLBACK_USER "$0"`) instead of simply aborting.

Trying to fix the quirks of individual commands will make your script unnecessarily complex and hard to debug. Every time you modify it, you'll have to do all the testing twice (as a regular user, then as `root`), and fix all the `root`-related bugs that arise. It's not a future-proof solution, so to say.

Answer (score 6):

By default files created with root accound have permissions like so:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 11月 17 23:25 rootfile.txt
```

Here file belongs to root user and root group, and is readable and writable by root, but only readable by others.

Simplest approach would be just to `chown` the file back to the original user.

```
chown username:group_name dummy.txt
```

You can use `$SUDO_USER` variable that is accessible only when `sudo` is called, like so:

```
chown "$SUDO_USER":"$SUDO_USER" dummy.txt
```

If you're running script as regular user, the `chown` part is not needed at all, so you might want to consider using if-statement or `&&` test to test for the case when script is run as root, and do something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch dummy.txt
[ $UID -eq 0 ] && chown "$SUDO_USER":"$SUDO_USER" dummy.txt
```

The above is recommended approach. There are others, like using `chmod` to change read-write-execute permissions for users and group, but it's not recommended.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But in Q I just explained simple scenario in real case original script will be creating many files. In linux can't we just simply ignore sudo ?

Comment: @Anonymous if you're executing the whole script with `sudo` , then no - you can't ignore it. Your option is either run script as regular user ( which I don't understand why you dont do , since you're simply creating a file for your user here ) or change file ownership like i show in my answer.

Comment: This is the most correct solution and it should not be that hard to scale up.