# Ignore sudo in bash script if using root

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, sudo, root

This question is not duplicate of [Ignore sudo in bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850736/ignore-sudo-in-bash-script)

---

I am making a docker image based on Ubuntu 14.04 docker image. As you know, root is default user in docker. 
When I ran a bash script to install a software, got

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I have tried `chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`,but it is not working.

---

This behavior is weird :

```
ls    (everyone can do this)
sudo ls   (you can't do this even if you are root)
```

Because I am building a docker image, I don't want to install uncorrelated packages to make sudo support root. But there are bunch of `sudo` in some bash scripts,so simply replacing `sudo` to empty may not a good choice.

So I'm wondering if is there any way to only ignore `sudo` when you are root

Comment: Well, if root is the only user, you are running the script as root and there is no need for sudo in your script. In general, IMO, sudo in scripts is sloppy as, rather then calling sudo within your script, simply remove sudo and run the script as root via `sudo script.sh` So ltl;dr simply remove sudo from your script, you can do this with sed.

Answer (score 7):

In your scripts, towards the beginning, define `sudo` to be a function that calls the actual `sudo` if needed:

```
sudo ()
{
    [[ $EUID = 0 ]] || set -- command sudo "$@"
    "$@"
}
```

`command sudo foo bar` tells bash to use the actual `sudo` command instead of functions or aliases. `$EUID` is the effective user ID, which might be different from `$UID`.

Comment: What exactly is the use of `set --`? I'm unable to understand the explanations given in `set --help` or `man set`.

Comment: @LoveXFCE it sets the arguments for the function in which it is run (or script/shell/subshell, if run outside a function). Say you run `sudo foo bar`. In the function, the arguments are `foo` and `bar`. If you're not root, `set` replaces these with `command`, `sudo`, `foo`, `bar`. Then the function runs the arguments as a command.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Does not work with pipes

An alternative to the answer by @muru is to use an alias and a check if the user is root. This avoids running the commands in function and the side effects that that might have. A solution that should work on all shells (tested on Alpine Linux):

```
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
  alias sudo=eval
fi
```

On more modern shells, the following can also be used:

```
if (( $EUID == 0 )); then
  alias sudo=eval
fi
```