# Remove sudo from one command in a large Bash script

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a large bash script that is supposed to install all dependencies for an application and then build the application itself.

I run the script with `sudo` because most of the commands require it, e. g.:

```
apt update
apt install -y libunwind8
apt install -y curl
...
```

Then it gets to building the application:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

When the script gets to these two commands it fails, giving me the following error:

```
/home/crispjam/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-98eb9fb8/.git: Permission denied
```

I did some research on this and found out that when interacting with a git repository you shouldn't use `sudo`.

I tried running the `npm install` outside of the script and it did, indeed, work, suggesting that `sudo` makes that command fail inside the script.

I've considered adding `sudo` to all the commands inside instead of running the script with `sudo` but I've read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script/425990) that for the most part it is not considered good practice.

In the top answer I read that you can drop the `sudo` privileges from a single command by prepending `sudo -u username` to it.

Is this good practice?

And how can I make this dynamic so that instead of using my `username` the script uses the name of the user running the script?

Comment: Related: [Ignore sudo in bash script](https://askubuntu.com/a/850747/178692) - if the script is being run via `sudo`, then it should be able to access the invoking user's uersname as `$SUDO_USER`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the folder permissions?

You can check it by right-clicking properties on the folder in your file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629605/getting-user-inside-shell-script-when-running-with-sudo) suggested using the command `logname`, which prints the user's login name.

To use it inside the script I simply modify the lines

```
npm install
npm run build
```

to:

```
sudo -u $(logname) npm install
sudo -u $(logname) npm run build
```